No logro comprender este código de Java que implementa Serializable. ¿Qué es y cómo funciona?
Este es un ejemplo de una clase que implementa Serializable, lo encontré en el material de apoyo de mis lecciones y estoy tratando de averiguar cómo funciona, no me queda claro todavía.
public class SerializableExample implements Serializable {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Singleton instance = Singleton.getInstance();

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = serializeSingletonInstance(instance);

        Singleton singleton = deserializeSingletonInstance(byteArrayOutputStream);
        Singleton singleton1 = deserializeSingletonInstance(byteArrayOutputStream);

        System.out.println("Checking ourInstance : " + singleton.getInstance());
        System.out.println("Checking ourInstance : " + singleton1.getInstance());
        System.out.println("=========================================================");
        System.out.println("Checking singleton : " + singleton);
        System.out.println("Checking singleton1 : " + singleton1);
    }

    public static ByteArrayOutputStream serializeSingletonInstance(Singleton instance) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        oos.writeObject(instance);
        oos.close();

        return byteArrayOutputStream;
    }

    public static Singleton deserializeSingletonInstance(ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        Singleton singleton = (Singleton) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

        return singleton;
    }

    public static class Singleton implements Serializable {
        private static Singleton ourInstance;

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
            if (ourInstance == null) {
                ourInstance = new Singleton();
            }
            return ourInstance;
        }

        private Singleton() {
        }

        private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {

            return getInstance();
        }
    }
}


Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué es lo poco que has entendido del código.

espero te encuentres bien.
El código implementa el patrón de diseño Singleton, el cual, funciona para poder tener una única instancia de una clase, el ejemplo que ingresas acá es una forma de desmostar que, aún aplicando una deserialización o una serialización de la clase, siempre se conserva el contrato, en otras palabras, se conserva la misma instancia.
Esto puedes notarlo en este fragmento de código donde se imprime el contenido de ambas instanciaciones de la clase Singleton para demostrar que ambos tienen la misma información.
Singleton singleton = deserializeSingletonInstance(byteArrayOutputStream);
Singleton singleton1 = deserializeSingletonInstance(byteArrayOutputStream);

System.out.println("Checking ourInstance : " + singleton.getInstance());
System.out.println("Checking ourInstance : " + singleton1.getInstance());
System.out.println("=========================================================");
System.out.println("Checking singleton : " + singleton);
System.out.println("Checking singleton1 : " + singleton1);

Cuando no se realiza con Singleton, lo que ocurriría es que, cada una de las instanciaciones, tendrían valores completamente distintos.
Espero que te haya sido de utilidad.
Saludos.
